# Android - findViewWithTag vs. findViewById

Tags: java, android

I started working with the findViewWithTag() method of a TextView to dynamically update text and have an issue updating the UI. The method works in that it finds the TextView and I can set the text. I verified this by inspecting the objects in code. Despite the method returning the correct TextView and the text property updating, the UI does not update. All code executes on the UI thread and the findViewById() method works as expected. What an I doing wrong here?

```
//This works as expected correctly
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview)).setText("NEW TEXT");

//This updates the test property, but does not update the UI.
((TextView) view.findViewWithTag("TAG TEXT")).setText("NEW TEXT");
```

These methods were tested in an Activity's onCreate method.

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure that you don't use "TAG TEXT" as a tag for another View

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this and it worked

```
    TextView loginTextView = (TextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.welcome_text_login);
    loginTextView.setTag("hello");
    TextView another=(TextView) view.findViewWithTag("hello");
    another.setText("signin");
```

Comment: I did the same thing and it did NOT update my UI. I guess in that it's consistent that's good. Something blocks the update when I use the findViewWithTag(). I'm stumped.

Comment: sorry buddy. I don't know why its not updating your text